# How to extract file location using Regular Expressions(VB.NET)

Tags: regex, vb.net, pattern-matching

I am facing a problem whereby I am given a string that contains a path to a file and the file's name and I only want to extract the path (without the file's name)

For example, I will receive something like

> C:\Users\OopsD\Projects\test.acdbd

and from that string I want to extract only

> C:\Users\OopsD\Projects

I was trying to create a RegEx to match a backslash followed by a word, followed by a dot followed by another word - this is to match the

> \test.acdbd

part and replace it with empty string so that the final result is

> C:\Users\OopsD\Projects

Can anyone, familiar with RegEx, help me on this one? Also, I will be using regular expressions quite a lot in the future. Is there a (free) program I can download to create regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really sure you need to be using Regex for such as simple task? How about this:

```
Dim file As New IO.FileInfo(" C:\Users\OopsD\Projects\test.acdbd")
MsgBox(file.Directory.FullName)
```

Regarding the free program on Regex, I would definitely recommend http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ - using it all the time. But you always have to consider alternatives, before going the Regex way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This is working perfectly. Reason I thought about using Regex is because I wanted to familiarize myself with it as I go along but obviously it was the wrong choice in this case. Thanks one more time

Answer (score 0):

The regex that you are looking for is as below:

```
[^/]+$
```

where,
`^ (caret):`Matches at the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to. Matches a position rather than a character. Most regex flavors have an option to make the caret match after line breaks (i.e. at the start of a line in a file) as well.

`$ (dollar):`Matches at the end of the string the regex pattern is applied to. Matches a position rather than a character. Most regex flavors have an option to make the dollar match before line breaks (i.e. at the end of a line in a file) as well. Also matches before the very last line break if the string ends with a line break.

`+ (plus):`Repeats the previous item once or more. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is matched only once.

More reference can be found out at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) link.

Many Regex softwares and tools are out there. Some of them are:

1. [www.gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/)
2. [www.txt2re.com](http://www.txt2re.com)
3. [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)- It is not just for Ruby.

Comment: would you be able to break it down and explain how that fits my requirements? sorry it's just i haven't really used regex'es before

Comment: also, when i do `MsgBox(Regex.Replace("C:\Users\OopsD\Projects\test.acdbd", "[^/]+$", String.Empty)) `
the message box returns nothing (empty)

Comment: You are using wrong method to do matching and replace. Search for an overload having 4 params.You can use this one also:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f.aspx

Comment: thank for your reply. It really isn't making any sense to me (maybe the chesty cough I have isn't helping :-\ ) I am using a similar syntax aren't I? Sorry to be a pain and thanks for your reply

Comment: No, you are using the different method really, check at the link given by me in comments. This method has to many overloads , you have to use method having 'RegexOptions' as one of the parameter.

Comment: I will have another go and let you know. thanks for your time and help